# How do I make a statement follow the same "if" rules as before

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a mini-quiz and I want the "try again" button to follow the same rules as the "if" statement as before the "else"

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int x;
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Find a number that can be divided by both 7 and 12");
        if ((x % 7 == 0) && (x % 12 == 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("well done, " +x+ " can be divided by 7 and 12");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the ReadLine after the else statement to follow the same rules as the "if" statement before it but it needs a whole new statement to follow and copy-pasting the statement seems like an inefficient solution.

Comment: You may wish to use `% 84`. There is no point checking 7 and 12 individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this kind of processing is done in a `while` loop, which continues to loop until the user answers correctly. So the key is then to create a condition that will become `false` when there's a correct answer.

Notice that we also have the `x` variable re-assigned to the `Console.ReadLine()` method in the `else` block, otherwise we're always comparing the old value of `x` and the loop will never end.

For example:

```
bool answeredCorrectly = false;

while (!answeredCorrectly)
{
    if ((x % 7 == 0) && (x % 12 == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("well done, " + x + " can be divided by 7 and 12");
        answeredCorrectly = true; // This will have us exit the while loop
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again.");
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

If you want to be really tricky about it, you could write a method that will get an integer from the user, and which takes function that can be used to validate that the input is correct (any method that takes in an `int` and returns a `bool`).

This way, you can create a validation method and pass that (along with the prompt for the user) to the method that gets an integer from the user.

Note that we're using the `int.TryParse` method to try to get an integer from the string input. This method is really handy because it does two things: First, it returns `true` if the parsing succeeds, and second, it returns the `int` value in an `out` parameter. This way we can use the return value to ensure they entered a number, and we can use the output parameter to see if the number meets our conditions:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool answeredCorrectly = false;

    while (!answeredCorrectly)
    {
        // Show message to user
        Console.Write(prompt);

        // Set to true only if int.TryParse succeeds and the validator returns true
        answeredCorrectly = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) &&
                            (validator == null || validator.Invoke(result));

        if (!answeredCorrectly) Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, please try again");
    }

    return result;
}
```

With this method in place, we can now call it from our main method as often as we like, with whatever validation we like, and we don't need to re-write all the looping code each time:

```
int x = GetIntFromUser("Enter a number that can be divided by both 7 and 12: ",
    i => i % 7 == 0 && i % 12 == 0);

x = GetIntFromUser("Enter a negative number: ", i => i < 0);

x = GetIntFromUser("Enter a number between 10 and 20: ", i => i > 10 && i < 20);
```

You could even use it to create a number guessing game with just a few lines of code!

```
int randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 101);

int x = GetIntFromUser("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to 100. Try to guess it: ", i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i < randomNumber
        ? $"{i} is too low - guess a larger number."
        : i > randomNumber ? $"{i} is too high - guess a smaller number." : "Correct!");
    return i == randomNumber;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a `while` block and `break;` on the successful condition?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int x;
        Console.WriteLine("Find a number that can be divided by both 7 and 12");
        while (true)
        { //Loop the code until it is broken out of
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if ((x % 7 == 0) && (x % 12 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("well done, " + x + " can be divided by 7 and 12");
                Console.ReadKey(); //Pause the program so it doesnt break out immediately
                break; //Break out of the while loop
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```